# VueX: why vuex store data does not update components data property?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In the following code, components (app.vue) `c2` property does not get updated when `increment` updates stores counter `this.$store.state.counter++;`

I know I can solve this by using `c2` as `computed` property but I would like to know why Vuex or vue does not initiate reactivity since the counter's value was updated by increment method.

**Store.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    counter: 0
  },
  mutation: {
    increment() {
      return this.$state.counter++;
    }
  }
});
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="increment">Increment</button>
    {{ c2 }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      c2: this.$store.state.counter
    };
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.$store.state.counter++;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuex uses something called "actions" and they look just like mutations, but instead of mutating the state, they commit mutations. You **can't** modify your Vuex store state like this:

```
methods: {
  increment() {
    this.$store.state.counter++
  }
}
```

Instead, you should create a actions object inside your store with an action:

```
actions: {
  increment (context) {
    context.commit('increment')
  }
}
```

Now, that code says this: "whenever you dispatch me (action), run the code inside the mutation called increment" which means: "commit the mutation called increment".

Another important thing is your component method called "increment". You should modify it to look like this:

```
methods: {
  increment() {
    this.$store.dispatch('increment')
  }
}
```

Now, whenever you call this method you will dispatch an action that will commit a mutation.

Finally, in order to get your state inside your component (the good way at least) would be using the `mapState` function that Vuex provides.

First, import this inside your component script tag:

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
```

And create a computed property like this:

```
computed: mapState([
  'counter'
])
```

This will give you access to the `counter` property that was define inside your store state. In that case, you can delete the return statement in your `data()` function and change your html in order to display the `counter` property:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="increment">Increment</button>
    {{ counter }}
  </div>
</template>
```

And that would be it!

Comment: Thanks for the answer however I would like to know the reason why Vuex or vue does not update the data property when the counter changes. If vuex is not used and anywhere in the same component or child component any reactive property changes that component is re-rendered (updated) by Vue.

Comment: The value of `counter` won't be updated because Vuex won't allow direct mutation of its value like you where doing. You have to use actions and mutations in order to achieve that change. Either way, it won't work.

Comment: @appu Also, is important to know that Vue reactivity concept need things to be done in a certain way in order to see them. Vuex state is an object and counter is a property of that object and they are not automatically watched by changing them just like you did. Applying those Vuex mechanism to mutate your store state   will be ok with this reactivity thing and you'll se changes.

Comment: `Vuex state is an object and counter is a property of that object and they are not automatically watched by changing them just like you did.` Thanks for this insight. :-)